# Selenium: How to find element by partial href?

Tags: c#, selenium, href, partial

Working code 1:

```
Driver.Instance.FindElement( By.XPath("//a[contains(@href,'" + PartialLinkHref + "')]" ));
```

Working code 2:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> linkList = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
for (int i = 0; i < linkList.Count ; i++)
{
     if (linkList[1].GetAttribute("href").Contains(PartialLinkHref))
     {
          element.SetElement(linkList[i]);
          return element;
          break;
     }
}
```

Comment: What is `PartialLinkHref`?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with your initial selector is that you're missing the `//` in front of the selector. the `//` tells XPath to search the whole html tree.

This should do the trick:

```
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href, 'long')]"))
```

If you want to find children of an element, use `.//` instead, e.g.

```
var element = Driver.Instance.FindElement("..some selector..")
var link = element.FindElement(".//a[contains(@href, 'long')]"))
```

If you want to find a link that contains **text** and not by the href attribute, you can use

```
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(), 'long')]"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is your selector, I think it's the object you're trying to return the results of `FindElements` to.

In c#, `FindElements` returns a `ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>` object, not a `List` object.  If you change your `linkList` definition, it should work:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> linkList = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
```

You may also need to add this `using`:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
```