# Finding an element by partial href (Python Selenium)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to access text from elements that have different xpaths but very predictable href schemes across multiple pages in a web database. Here are some examples:

```html
<a href="/mathscinet/search/mscdoc.html?code=65J22,(35R30,47A52,65J20,65R30,90C30)">
65J22 (35R30 47A52 65J20 65R30 90C30) </a>
```

In this example I would want to extract "65J22 (35R30 47A52 65J20 65R30 90C30)"

```html
<a href="/mathscinet/search/mscdoc.html?code=05C80,(05C15)">
05C80 (05C15) </a>
```

In this example I would want to extract "05C80 (05C15)". My web scraper would not be able to search by xpath directly due to the xpaths of my desired elements changing between pages, so I am looking for a more roundabout approach.

My main idea is to use the fact that every href contains "/mathscinet/search/mscdoc.html?code=". Selenium can't directly search for hrefs, but I was thinking of doing something similar to this [C# implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572892/selenium-how-to-find-element-by-partial-href):

```
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href, 'long')]"))
```

To port this over to python, the only analogous method I could think of would be to use the [`in` operator](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details), but I am not sure how the syntax will work when everything is nested in a find_element_by_xpath. How would I bring all of these ideas together to obtain my desired text?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a['/mathscinet/search/mscdoc.html?code=' in @href]").text
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I right understand you want to locate all elements, that have same partial href. You can use this:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/mathscinet/search/mscdoc.html')]")
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

or if you want to locate one element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/mathscinet/search/mscdoc.html')]").text
```

This will give a list of all elements located.

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared @AndreiSuvorkov's answer would possibly cater to your current requirement. Perhaps you can get much more granular and construct an optimized *xpath* by:

- Instead of using `contains` using **`starts-with`**
- Include the **`?code=`** part of the `@href` attribute
- Your effective code block will be:

  ```
  all_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'/mathscinet/search/mscdoc.html?code=')]")
  for elem in all_elements:
      print(elem.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```